# how to move a 3d object forward in the direction its pointing in three.js

Tags: three.js

i have a 3d car in my three.js world i want to move it in the direction its pointing after it rotates how whould i do so
i have a car that can go in z direction but not based on the direction its looking

```
//onkeydown forward 
car.position.z -= 0.02;//low number since it updates around 60 fps
//onkeydown backword 
car.position.z += 0.02;
//onkeydown right 

it goes forward and backword but not in the direction its pointing it goes on z axis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `car.translateZ(distance);` It moves the object along its local z-axis, instead of the global position, which means it respects the object's rotation. Read more about it [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.translateZ).

Comment: thanks so much ps why is Y depth and Z up and down ?

Comment: also if you dont mind explaining is there a physical difference between translateX and position.x and i mean i heared tht not to use translateX becuse dosnt actualy mve object whats that mean       please

Comment: In WebGL, (and therefore Three.js), +Y is up, +Z is toward the viewer, +X is to the right. You should look [at the editor](https://threejs.org/editor/), it has an axis gizmo that could help you visualize it better. There's no explanation why, each engine uses its own coordinate system [and it's a complete disaster](https://twitter.com/FreyaHolmer/status/1325556229410861056). You just have to get used to what you're using.

Comment: @YosefefriemRosner Where did you hear not to use `translateX()`? It's perfectly valid to use.

Comment: first of all when i set translateZ it went up ? but with position.z it goes in you know why ? second i  read it hear on stack overflow

Comment: Because of its rotation. If it’s been rotated, then its local Z-axis could be pointing in any direction. TranslateZ respects the object’s local orientation, it doesn’t follow the global axis. Did you import it from somewhere? The asset might already have a rotation applied to it.